# How set TimeZone for each virtual host in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7, virtual-hosts

I have web apps for **3 regions**(Mongolia,Turkmenia, etc). And they are deployed on **tomcat's virtual host**. Now I need set **timezone** for each application. How can I do that?
I implemented **ServerContextListener** interface for each apps to set **TimeZone**:

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    TimeZone timeZone=TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Ulan_Bator");
//  TimeZone timeZone=TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Ashgabat");
    timeZone.setDefault(timeZone);
}
```

But after deploy each apps has same TimeZone.

P.S: Sorry for my English :)

Comment: Turkmenmi sen dos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `ZoneId`, not `TimeZone`

The terrible legacy date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

`TimeZone` in replaced by [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) & [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Ulan_Bator" ) ;
```

## Avoid default time zone

Avoid relying on the JVM’s current default time zone.

There is **only *one* default time zone for the JVM**. Calling `TimeZone.setDefault` immediately affects all code in all threads of all apps within that JVM.

> But after deploy each apps has same TimeZone.

So you cannot set a different default time zone per web app. If all the web apps are running in the same Servlet container, then all the web apps share the same default time zone.

## Pass desired time zone

A better approach is to explicitly pass the desired/expected time zone as the optional argument to various *java.time* methods. For example, if you want to capture the current moment as seen in a particular time zone, pass the desired `ZoneId` object to the `now` method.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Ashgabat" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Rather than depend on the JVM’s current default time zone, set a time zone for each of your web apps.

### `ServletContextListener::contextInitialized`

You were close to a solution. When each web app launches, you need to specify its default. The place to do that is in the [`contextInitialized`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized-javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent-) method in your class implementing the [`ServletContextListener`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) as shown in your Question.

Inside that method, specify the desired time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Ashgabat" ) ;
```

But that variable goes out of scope and disappears at the end of the `contextInitialized` method. So we need to store a reference to that `ZoneId` object somewhere. But where? The Servlet spec defines a place just for such “global” variables or constants you need across code within your app.

Your `contextInitialized` method is passed a [`ServletContextEvent`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContextEvent.html). That object holds a reference to the [`ServletContext`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) object representing the current instance of your web app that is launching.

```
ServletContext myWebAppContext = servletContextEvent.getContext() ;
```

### Attributes (key-value store)

That `ServletContext` conveniently maintains a simple key-value store of “attributes”. The key is a `String`, the value an `Object`. We can make up a string name for our per-web-app default time zone, and pass the `ZoneId` as the `Object` value. Pass these to [`ServletContext::setAttribute`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-).

```
String key = "com.example.acme_webapp.zoneid" ;
Object value = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Ashgabat" ) ;
myWebAppContext.setAttribute( key , value ) ;
```

In your app's code, [look up the context](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+servlet+get+current+context&t=osx&ia=web) and attribute anytime you need. Ask the Servlet request being serviced for its context.

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext() ;
```

Ask for the value from the stored attribute.

```
Object value = context.getAttribute( "com.example.acme_webapp.zoneid.mongolia" ) ;
```

Cast the `Object` back to a `ZoneId`. We know that should work, but for defensive programming you may want to check `instanceof`.

```
ZoneId z = ( ZoneId ) value ;
```

Then proceed with your work. Perhaps you want to capture the time as seen in that zone, just as we discussed above.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Tip: You might want to define an enum to handle those multiple region strings for the attributes names. Copy-pasting string values is risk business. See [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

### Thread-safety

Note that while each web app instance has its own [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) object, that object is being shared across threads. A Servlet environment is by definition highly-threaded, each request being serviced on a thread. So that `ZoneId` is being shared across any number of threads. But that is okay. Fortunately, the *java.time* classes are [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) by design, using the [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) pattern.

Obligatory Servlet threading concurrency tip: Anyone doing Servlet coding should be reading and re-reading this book: [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/127932.Java_Concurrency_in_Practice?from_search=true) by Brian Goetz, Tim Peierls, Joshua Bloch, Joseph Bowbeer, David Holmes, Doug Lea.

Answer (score 0):

You can set JVM timezone for tomcat. For that you need to add below option in your JVM options, in tomcat configuration file.

`-Duser.timezone=UTC`

Use your timezone in place of UTC. It will start your JVM in that timezone.