# Timezone Springboot Tomcat 8 AS

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, timezone, tomcat8

On my spring boot app running on Tomcat 8 i have this code into SpringBootServletInitializer:

```
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
} }
```

On my tomcat application server, i have some war write with spring framework, the problem is that all application inside my tomcat has been changed timezone according to my app, and this is wrong.

How can i set the timezone only for my application, without affecting the timezone of the other apps into tomcat?

Thanks

Comment: Would use 1 instance of tomcat per timezone (via `-Duser.timezone=??` params)  or simply use the webserver included with spring boot standalone jar. Trying to workaround is just too errorprone

Answer (score 1):

The JVM running your Tomcat server has only one default time zone. Changing that default immediately affects all code in all threads of all apps running within that JVM. Therefore calling `TimeZone.setDefault` is almost never the right thing to do.

Learn about the modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy date-time classes. Specifically, use `ZoneId` & `ZoneOffset` rather than `TimeZone`. For UTC, use the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

Learn about Servlet context listeners setting objects as key-value pairs in the “attributes” store on the Servlet context. You might store your desired `ZoneId` object there. Or perhaps Spring has some way to help with this. (I do not use Spring.)

See my Answer to [this similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31934995/642706) for more info.